# Как мне решить проблему PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

Ребят, я ноутбук переустановил с семёрки на десятку. Щас, я на даче и раздаю интернет с телефона на комп без ограничений. Я установил: python, pyqt5, pip upgrade, pyqt5-tools, sqlite3 и всё. Дальше я создал папку. В папке создал файл `main.py`. Дальше я открыл `designer.exe` в `Python > Libs > site-packages > pyqt5-tools > qt > bin > designer.exe`

Дальше выскакивает ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но, я решил эту проблему, в папку pluguns там где `designer.exe` я добавил `platform` и туда `"qminimal.dll"` и `"qwindows.dll"` - так я открыл `designer.exe`. И дальше я просто запустил мой файл. И эта же ошибка вылетает.

Для понятия: я не мог открыть `designer.exe` с этой ошибкой выше(скриншот). Я сделал про папки. Дальше я открыл `designer.exe`, но не смог запустить свой файл с такой же ошибкой.

Что делать?

python: 3.8.1

Comment: А переустановить Qt и PyQt пробовали?

Comment: @cauf ага, читал что может мне помочь в конце ошибки

Comment: только у меня **Py**qt. Обычного Qt нету даже дома на компе, а там всё работает

Comment: pyqt это обертка над Qt, так что, если работает приложение с pyqt, то библиотека Qt установлена. Может вы ее сами не устанавливали, а она установилась, как часть какой-то другой программы.

Comment: Может быть, но кажется что нет.